# <no name> labels in minitest result

Tags: rubymine

Recently, when running test (using minitest 5.11.1 and minitest-reporters 1.1.19), the results are under label <no name> and they are gradually nested like this:

[image: this]

making it difficult to read. I have made no manual updates of RubyMine. What is causing it? How to get rid of it?

Comment: I just started getting this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this issue by pinning your Gemfile to minitest 5.10.3.

My guess is that it could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters/issues/248) (even though that is for a different reporter).

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to the issue!